# Mac OS command to resolve hostnames like "getent" on Linux

Tags: osx, hostname, mdns

I would like a command that will resolve a hostname to an IP address, in the same way that a normal program would resolve the hostname.  In other words, it has to take into account mDNS (`.local`) and `/etc/hosts`, as well as regular DNS.  So that rules out `host`, `dig`, and `nslookup`, since all three of those tools only use regular DNS and won't resolve `.local` addresses.

On Linux, the `getent` command [does exactly what I want](https://serverfault.com/questions/303716/linux-command-line-utility-to-resolve-host-names-using-etc-hosts-first).  However, `getent` does not exist on OS X.

Is there a Mac OS X equivalent of `getent`?  I'm aware that I could write one in a few lines using `getaddrinfo`, and that's what I'll do if I have to, but I was just wondering if there was already a standard command that could do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think `dscacheutil` is what you're looking for. It supports caching, /etc/hosts, mDNS (for .local).

```
dscacheutil -q host -a name foo.local
```

Another option is `dns-sd`

```
dns-sd -q foo.local
```

[More information about dnscacheutil](https://ss64.com/osx/dscacheutil.html).

Comment: What is a clear example. For example localhost? How to use, what is the output? It does not work.

Comment: Another example `dns-sd -G v4v6 raspberrypi-rubelagu.local` that will show the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses of my raspberry pi on my local network (the raspberry was configured with `raspberrypi-rubelagu` as hostname , the default is just `raspberrypi)

Comment: For others looking for a clear example, the "host" and "name" parts are part of the command, not arguments to substitute. Example: `dscacheutil -q host -a name google.com`

Answer (score 4):

*(Building on [user422009's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373415/237454))*

Add this to your **~/.bash_profile**:

```
getent() {
  [ "$1" == "hosts" ] && shift
  for x
  do
    echo $x $(dscacheutil -q host -a name $x | awk '/^ip_address/{print $NF}')
  done
}
```

Then either open a new terminal or source your bash_profile:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

And then it'll work:

```
$ getent hosts www.example.com
www.example.com 93.184.216.34
```

Comment: This could end up being _very_ confusing as you're effectively 'shadowing' another command with a Bash function and, if you forget that you shadowed it, you might be confused why `getent` doesn't seem to work as expected on your computer.

Comment: Thanks, if you change "==" to "=" it fixes zsh error "getent:1: = not found" while remaining bash compatible.